# How to get the value from the Table and using it in the same Table?

Tags: mysql

In the table we have an ID column,whenever new record is inserted ,consecutive no in ID should be included, but there is no auto increment  for that column also . 
I need a answer for the following query

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT(ID) VALUES(SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM STUDENT );
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you use an `IDENTITY` (SQL Server) or `AUTO_INCREMENT` (MySQL - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) modifier on your column, you won't have to do this.

Comment: The think i don't want to use Auto_Increment modifier on that column.

Comment: ----------why?---------------

Comment: Am a newbie,i want to write a insert script, Sometimes ID will start in 1000, after 1000 records i may also start ID as 5000 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you are trying to do with something similar to what you have.  The biggest problem I see is what to do if there are no records in the table, which I've handled with a `case` statement.

`Auto_Increment` would be better for this type of issue, since it can guarantee the id.  This code could potentially have an issue where connection A has selected a max ID but not inserted it, yet, while connection B could have already selected and inserted the ID that connection A has but did not insert, yet.  You can still code like this, you just have to be able to handle the issue if it arises.

Sample code:

```
Insert Into Student(ID) 
SELECT case when not exists(select * from student) then 1
      else MAX(ID) + 1 END FROM STUDENT;
```

Larger sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dae11/1

```
[SQL Fiddle][1]

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

    create table Student(
      ID int
    );

    Insert Into Student(ID) 
    SELECT case when not exists(select * from student) then 1
          else MAX(ID) + 1 END FROM STUDENT;



    Insert Into Student(ID) 
    SELECT case when not exists(select * from student) then 1
          else MAX(ID) + 1 END FROM STUDENT;


    Insert Into Student(ID) 
    SELECT case when not exists(select * from student) then 1
          else MAX(ID) + 1 END FROM STUDENT;


    Insert Into Student(ID) 
    SELECT case when not exists(select * from student) then 1
          else MAX(ID) + 1 END FROM STUDENT;


**Query 1**:

    select * from student

**[Results][2]**:

    | ID |
    |----|
    |  1 |
    |  2 |
    |  3 |
    |  4 |



  [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dae11/1

  [2]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dae11/1/0
```